# How to dynamically set the price and quantity for a product?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to create a PayPal form on which the user can set the price and the product quantity, but have had no success.

The form is POST as expected but the values in the checkout page are not updated. It must run on front-end environment, no server-side code involved.

This is the form:

```
<form id="product-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xyz">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Amount">Valor</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="price" type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200" placeholder="R$" value="1.00"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Quantidade">Quantity</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="quantity-input" type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="1.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">


        <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_BR/BR/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" alt="PayPal - A maneira fácil e segura de enviar pagamentos online!" onclick="validator()" />
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_BR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

This is the JS I'm using to validate the form submitted.

```
var priceInput = $('#price'),
            amountInput = $('#amount'),
            quantityInput = $('#quantity-input'),
            quantity = $('#quantity'),
            validator = function validator () {
                var value = priceInput.val(),
                    quant = quantityInput.val(),
                    val = value.replace('R$ ', ''),
                    amount = parseInt( val );

                if ( !amount ) {
                    window.alert('Min value is 1.00');
                    priceInput.focus();
                    return;
                }

                amountInput.val(val);
                quantity.val(quant);

                $('#product-form').submit();
            };

        $(function() {
            priceInput.maskMoney({ 'prefix': 'R$ ' });
        });
```

The value remains the default one that was previously set for the product.
[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this?